# Docusign Tabs missing only when using multiple documents

Tags: vb.net, winforms, docusignapi

I have a Winforms vb.net app that sends pdfs to docusign for signing. Here is my issue.

Scenario #1: pdf #1 sent alone and all tabs show as expected

Scenario #2: pdf #2 sent alone and all tabs show as expected

Scenario #3: pdf #1 & pdf #2 sent together, 4 of the 6 tabs are missing on pdf #1. The tabs missing are Initial, DateSigned and Date. Signature & FullName show as expected for pdf #1. All tabs also show correctly for pdf #2.

I am using pretty unique AnchorStrings for the missing tabs. But the Signature & FullName AnchorStrings are the same for both documents.

I am also identifying the DocumentId, RecipientId and PageNumber as required per the API Reference.

I am coming to the conclusion we will have to send each document desperately.

```
    'Public Sub SendForSignature(ByRef Docs As List(Of DocToSign), DocSigner As Signer)
        Try
            If Not UserHasLogin(User.Id) Then
                Throw New Exception("You do not have DocuSign credentials saved. Save your credentials in your User Settings to use DocuSign.")
            End If

            If Docs.Count = 0 Then
                Exit Try
            End If
            If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DocSigner.Name) Then
                Throw New Exception("No recipient name found.")
            End If
            If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DocSigner.Email) Then
                Throw New Exception("No recipient email address found.")
            End If

            If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DocSigner.RecipientId) Then
                DocSigner.RecipientId = "1"
            End If
            If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DocSigner.RoutingOrder) Then
                DocSigner.RoutingOrder = "1"
            End If

            'Create Envelope
            Dim envDef As New EnvelopeDefinition() With {
                .EmailSubject = $"Signature Requested from {User.FirstName}",
                .EmailBlurb = "Please sign the document. Thank you!"}
            envDef.Documents = New List(Of Document)()
            envDef.CustomFields = New CustomFields()
            envDef.Recipients = New Recipients()

            'Used for Documentid
            Dim i As Integer = 1

            For Each pdf As DocToSign In Docs

                If Not File.Exists(pdf.Path) Then
                    Throw New Exception($"PDF file was not found at '{pdf.Path}'.")
                End If
                If Not Path.GetExtension(pdf.Path).ToLower.EndsWith("pdf") Then
                    Throw New Exception("File path did not end with pdf, invalid file format.")
                End If

                Dim filebytes As Byte() = File.ReadAllBytes(pdf.Path)

                Dim lcf As New List(Of ListCustomField)
                lcf.Add(New ListCustomField With {.Name = "ReferenceGUID", .Value = pdf.ReferenceGUID, .Required = "true", .Show = "false"})
                lcf.Add(New ListCustomField With {.Name = "UserId", .Value = User.Id.ToString, .Required = "true", .Show = "false"})
                envDef.CustomFields.ListCustomFields = lcf

                'Add a document to the envelope 
                Dim doc As New Document()
                doc.DocumentBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(filebytes)
                doc.Name = Path.GetFileName(pdf.Path)
                doc.DocumentId = i.ToString()
                doc.DocumentFields = New List(Of NameValue)
                doc.DocumentFields.Add(New NameValue With {.Name = "ReferenceGUID", .Value = pdf.ReferenceGUID})
                doc.ApplyAnchorTabs = "true"
                envDef.Documents.Add(doc)

                'Move Tabs per Document
                Select Case pdf.DocumentTypeId
                    Case 2 'Client Lease
                        'Change for Master Leases
                        If pdf.IsSubLease Then

                        Else
                            SetupClientLease(DocSigner, i.ToString)
                        End If

                    Case 18 'Client NTV
                        SetupClientNTV(DocSigner, i.ToString)

                    Case 7 'Addendum
                        SetupClientAddendum(DocSigner, i.ToString)

                    Case 6 'SOP
                        SetupClientSOP(DocSigner, i.ToString)

                    Case 41 'Master Rental Agreement
                        Dim ECHSigner As New Signer With {.Name = User.FullName, .Email = User.EmailAddress, .RecipientId = "2", .RoutingOrder = "1"}
                        DocSigner.RoutingOrder = "2"
                        envDef.Recipients.Signers.Add(ECHSigner)
                        SetupMasterRentalAgreement(DocSigner, ECHSigner, i.ToString)

                End Select

                'Set next doc id
                i += 1
            Next

            'Add a recipient to sign the documeent
            envDef.Recipients.Signers = New List(Of Signer)()
            envDef.Recipients.Signers.Add(DocSigner)

            'Set envelope status to "sent" to immediately send the signature request 
            envDef.Status = "sent"

            'Use the EnvelopesApi to send the signature request! 
            Dim envelopesApi As New EnvelopesApi()
            Dim envelopeSummary As EnvelopeSummary = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(accountid, envDef)

        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New Exception(ex.Message, ex.InnerException)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub SetupClientNTV(ByRef signer As Signer, DocId As String)
        Try
            ' Create a |SignHere| tab somewhere on the document for the recipient to sign 
            signer.Tabs = New Tabs()
            signer.Tabs.SignHereTabs = New List(Of SignHere)
            signer.Tabs.InitialHereTabs = New List(Of InitialHere)
            signer.Tabs.DateTabs = New List(Of [Date])
            signer.Tabs.FullNameTabs = New List(Of FullName)
            signer.Tabs.DateSignedTabs = New List(Of DateSigned)

            'Signature Tab
            Dim signHere As New SignHere() With {
                .AnchorString = "Guest Signature",
                .AnchorXOffset = "2",
                .AnchorYOffset = "-12",
                .DocumentId = DocId,
                .RecipientId = "1",
                .AnchorMatchWholeWord = "true",
                .AnchorCaseSensitive = "true",
                .AnchorIgnoreIfNotPresent = "true",
                .PageNumber = "1"}

            'Full Name Tab
            Dim fullName As New FullName With {
                .AnchorString = "Guest Printed Name",
                .AnchorXOffset = "0",
                .AnchorYOffset = "-12",
                .DocumentId = DocId,
                .AnchorMatchWholeWord = "true",
                .AnchorCaseSensitive = "true",
                .AnchorIgnoreIfNotPresent = "true",
                .PageNumber = "1"}

            'Date Signed Tabs
            Dim dateSigned As New DateSigned() With {
                .AnchorString = "Date Signed",
                .AnchorXOffset = "0",
                .AnchorYOffset = "-12",
                .DocumentId = DocId,
                .AnchorMatchWholeWord = "true",
                .AnchorCaseSensitive = "true",
                .AnchorIgnoreIfNotPresent = "true",
                .PageNumber = "1"}

            'Date Tabs
            Dim ntvdate As New [Date] With {
                .AnchorString = "Initial ONLY ONE",
                .AnchorXOffset = "292",
                .AnchorYOffset = "26",
                .DocumentId = DocId,
                .AnchorMatchWholeWord = "true",
                .AnchorCaseSensitive = "true",
                .AnchorIgnoreIfNotPresent = "true",
                .PageNumber = "1",
                .ConditionalParentLabel = "initial1",
                .ConditionalParentValue = "on",
                .Width = 100}

            'Initial Tabs
            Dim initial1 As New InitialHere With {
                .AnchorString = "Initial ONLY ONE",
                .AnchorXOffset = "2",
                .AnchorYOffset = "41",
                .DocumentId = DocId,
                .AnchorMatchWholeWord = "true",
                .AnchorCaseSensitive = "true",
                .AnchorIgnoreIfNotPresent = "true",
                .PageNumber = "1",
                .Optional = "true",
                .TabLabel = "initial1",
                .ScaleValue = "0.75"} 'Scale value is size - 1.0 is full size, 0.5 is 50% size

            Dim initial2 As New InitialHere With {
                .AnchorString = "Initial ONLY ONE",
                .AnchorXOffset = "2",
                .AnchorYOffset = "82",
                .DocumentId = DocId,
                .AnchorMatchWholeWord = "true",
                .AnchorCaseSensitive = "true",
                .AnchorIgnoreIfNotPresent = "true",
                .PageNumber = "1",
                .Optional = "true",
                .TabLabel = "initail2",
                .ScaleValue = "0.75"}


            signer.Tabs.SignHereTabs.Add(signHere)
            signer.Tabs.DateTabs.Add(ntvdate)
            signer.Tabs.FullNameTabs.Add(fullName)
            signer.Tabs.DateSignedTabs.Add(dateSigned)
            signer.Tabs.InitialHereTabs.Add(initial1)
            signer.Tabs.InitialHereTabs.Add(initial2)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New Exception(ex.Message, ex.InnerException)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub SetupClientSOP(ByRef signer As Signer, DocId As String)
        Try
            ' Create a |SignHere| tab somewhere on the document for the recipient to sign 
            signer.Tabs = New Tabs()
            signer.Tabs.SignHereTabs = New List(Of SignHere)
            signer.Tabs.TextTabs = New List(Of Text)
            signer.Tabs.FullNameTabs = New List(Of FullName)
            signer.Tabs.DateSignedTabs = New List(Of DateSigned)
            signer.Tabs.RadioGroupTabs = New List(Of RadioGroup)

            Dim rg As New RadioGroup With {
                .DocumentId = DocId,
                .GroupName = "radios",
                .RecipientId = "1",
                .Radios = New List(Of Radio)}


            'Signature Tab
            Dim signHere As New SignHere() With {
                .AnchorString = "Guest Signature",
                .AnchorXOffset = "3",
                .AnchorYOffset = "-11",
                .DocumentId = DocId,
                .AnchorMatchWholeWord = "true",
                .AnchorCaseSensitive = "true",
                .AnchorIgnoreIfNotPresent = "true",
                .PageNumber = "1"}

            'Radio Tabs
            Dim radio1 As New Radio With {
                .AnchorString = "Credit Card on File",
                .AnchorXOffset = "-27",
                .AnchorYOffset = "-3",
                .AnchorMatchWholeWord = "true",
                .AnchorCaseSensitive = "true",
                .AnchorIgnoreIfNotPresent = "true",
                .Required = "true",
                .Selected = "true",
                .PageNumber = "1"}

            Dim radio2 As New Radio With {
                .AnchorString = "Auto Debit my",
                .AnchorXOffset = "-27",
                .AnchorYOffset = "-3",
                .AnchorMatchWholeWord = "true",
                .AnchorCaseSensitive = "true",
                .AnchorIgnoreIfNotPresent = "true",
                .Required = "true",
                .Selected = "false",
                .PageNumber = "1"}

            Dim radio3 As New Radio With {
                .AnchorString = "Postal Mail (",
                .AnchorXOffset = "-27",
                .AnchorYOffset = "-3",
                .AnchorMatchWholeWord = "true",
                .AnchorCaseSensitive = "true",
                .AnchorIgnoreIfNotPresent = "true",
                .Required = "true",
                .Selected = "false",
                .PageNumber = "1"}

            Dim radio4 As New Radio With {
                .AnchorString = "Wire Transfer",
                .AnchorXOffset = "-27",
                .AnchorYOffset = "-3",
                .AnchorMatchWholeWord = "true",
                .AnchorCaseSensitive = "true",
                .AnchorIgnoreIfNotPresent = "true",
                .Required = "true",
                .Selected = "false",
                .PageNumber = "1"}


            'Text Tabs (For email address - Using EmailAddress is not optional)
            Dim emailHere As New Text With {
                .AnchorString = "Email address where invoices should be sent:",
                .AnchorXOffset = "160",
                .AnchorYOffset = "-3",
                .DocumentId = DocId,
                .AnchorMatchWholeWord = "true",
                .AnchorCaseSensitive = "true",
                .Required = "false",
                .PageNumber = "1",
                .Width = 225}

            'Full Name Tab
            Dim fullName As New FullName With {
                .AnchorString = "Guest Printed Name",
                .AnchorXOffset = "0",
                .AnchorYOffset = "-11",
                .DocumentId = DocId,
                .AnchorMatchWholeWord = "true",
                .AnchorCaseSensitive = "true",
                .AnchorIgnoreIfNotPresent = "true",
                .PageNumber = "1"}

            'Date Tab
            Dim dateHere As New DateSigned() With {
                .AnchorString = "Date:",
                .AnchorXOffset = "20",
                .AnchorYOffset = "-3",
                .DocumentId = DocId,
                .AnchorMatchWholeWord = "true",
                .AnchorCaseSensitive = "true",
                .PageNumber = "1"}


            rg.Radios.Add(radio1)
            rg.Radios.Add(radio2)
            rg.Radios.Add(radio3)
            rg.Radios.Add(radio4)
            signer.Tabs.SignHereTabs.Add(signHere)
            signer.Tabs.RadioGroupTabs.Add(rg)
            signer.Tabs.TextTabs.Add(emailHere)
            signer.Tabs.FullNameTabs.Add(fullName)
            signer.Tabs.DateSignedTabs.Add(dateHere)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New Exception(ex.Message, ex.InnerException)
        End Try
    End Sub`
```

Request Body

```
'{
"documents": [
    {
        "documentId": "1",
        "name": "2teevgqk2dm.pdf",
        "documentFields": [
            {
                "name": "ReferenceGUID",
                "value": "2582db83-cf6e-4611-9daf-321f40a7440a"
            }
        ],
        "documentBase64": "[Base64 data omitted]",
        "applyAnchorTabs": "true"
    },
    {
        "documentId": "2",
        "name": "dwwkrtmjwk3.pdf",
        "documentFields": [
            {
                "name": "ReferenceGUID",
                "value": "2582db83-cf6e-4611-9daf-321f40a7440a"
            }
        ],
        "documentBase64": "[Base64 data omitted]",
        "applyAnchorTabs": "true"
    }
],
"recipients": {
    "signers": [
        {
            "tabs": {
                "signHereTabs": [
                    {
                        "documentId": "2",
                        "pageNumber": "1",
                        "anchorString": "Guest Signature",
                        "anchorXOffset": "3",
                        "anchorYOffset": "-11",
                        "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                        "anchorCaseSensitive": "true",
                        "anchorMatchWholeWord": "true"
                    }
                ],
                "fullNameTabs": [
                    {
                        "documentId": "2",
                        "pageNumber": "1",
                        "anchorString": "Guest Printed Name",
                        "anchorXOffset": "0",
                        "anchorYOffset": "-11",
                        "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                        "anchorCaseSensitive": "true",
                        "anchorMatchWholeWord": "true"
                    }
                ],
                "dateSignedTabs": [
                    {
                        "documentId": "2",
                        "pageNumber": "1",
                        "anchorString": "Date:",
                        "anchorXOffset": "20",
                        "anchorYOffset": "-3",
                        "anchorCaseSensitive": "true",
                        "anchorMatchWholeWord": "true"
                    }
                ],
                "textTabs": [
                    {
                        "width": 225,
                        "required": "false",
                        "documentId": "2",
                        "pageNumber": "1",
                        "anchorString": "Email address where invoices should be sent:",
                        "anchorXOffset": "160",
                        "anchorYOffset": "-3",
                        "anchorCaseSensitive": "true",
                        "anchorMatchWholeWord": "true"
                    }
                ],
                "radioGroupTabs": [
                    {
                        "documentId": "2",
                        "recipientId": "1",
                        "groupName": "radios",
                        "radios": [
                            {
                                "pageNumber": "1",
                                "anchorString": "Credit Card on File",
                                "anchorXOffset": "-27",
                                "anchorYOffset": "-3",
                                "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                                "anchorCaseSensitive": "true",
                                "anchorMatchWholeWord": "true",
                                "selected": "true",
                                "required": "true"
                            },
                            {
                                "pageNumber": "1",
                                "anchorString": "Auto Debit my",
                                "anchorXOffset": "-27",
                                "anchorYOffset": "-3",
                                "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                                "anchorCaseSensitive": "true",
                                "anchorMatchWholeWord": "true",
                                "selected": "false",
                                "required": "true"
                            },
                            {
                                "pageNumber": "1",
                                "anchorString": "Postal Mail (",
                                "anchorXOffset": "-27",
                                "anchorYOffset": "-3",
                                "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                                "anchorCaseSensitive": "true",
                                "anchorMatchWholeWord": "true",
                                "selected": "false",
                                "required": "true"
                            },
                            {
                                "pageNumber": "1",
                                "anchorString": "Wire Transfer",
                                "anchorXOffset": "-27",
                                "anchorYOffset": "-3",
                                "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                                "anchorCaseSensitive": "true",
                                "anchorMatchWholeWord": "true",
                                "selected": "false",
                                "required": "true"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            "name": "Joe Blow",
            "email": "test@test.com",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "routingOrder": "1"
        }
    ]
},
"customFields": {
    "listCustomFields": [
        {
            "name": "ReferenceGUID",
            "show": "false",
            "required": "true",
            "value": "2582db83-cf6e-4611-9daf-321f40a7440a"
        },
        {
            "name": "UserId",
            "show": "false",
            "required": "true",
            "value": "14"
        }
    ]
},
"status": "sent",
"emailSubject": "Signature Requested",
"emailBlurb": "Please sign the document. Thank you!"
    }'
```

Comment: Can you please share your Request Body & the API you are using.

Comment: Praveen I am using the NuGet package version 2.0.6 that references a dll, not the Rest or Soap API. So I do not see a way to get you the Request Body.

Comment: Can you then share your VB.NET code.

Comment: To much code/characters to share on here, it wont let me..........

Comment: It is difficult to provide a solution without seeing your code.

Comment: I understand, unfortunately this is DucoSigns only solution for support. Not the best support if you ask me. We may have to look at other solutions besides DocuSign. As I said above, each document work if sent individually. The only thing that changes when I send both is a add another document to the envelop and give it id 2 instead of 1, then assign documentid 2 to all of the tabs for the 2nd document.

Comment: When posting your code, leave out the document source. Also, narrow down your problem and include the smaller test case's code.

Comment: I finally figured out how to add my code, jeeeez what a pain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, each document gets its own id, unique for the envelope. And each anchor (autoplace) tab needs to include a documentId which specifies the document the tab belongs to.

If you have two documents and each gets a SignHere tab, then you need two different SignHere tab definitions, one for each document. It doesn't matter that the two tabs use the same anchor string text.

Comment: Thanks Larry, that is how I have had it setup. For some reason there is a conflict and it is not rendering correctly.

Comment: @Chris -- I'm sorry you're having this trouble. Please edit your question (use the edit link below it) to add your request body to your question. You can use the API logger to see your request. See https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-signature-api-logging-made-easy/

Comment: Larry, I setup the Logger and on the POST I am getting an status of error. "Problem: Couldn't fetch file" even though the files seem to be working.

Comment: It appears the tabs for document 2 are not being added to the request at all. Maybe because they are not added to the same list of tabs.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the issue was that I was creating multiple list of tabs instead of just one list for each tab type. So only the first list was working.

I had to add the following code before I looped through to setup the tabs for each document.

```
            DocSigner.Tabs = New Tabs()
            DocSigner.Tabs.SignHereTabs = New List(Of SignHere)
            DocSigner.Tabs.InitialHereTabs = New List(Of InitialHere)
            DocSigner.Tabs.TextTabs = New List(Of Text)
            DocSigner.Tabs.FullNameTabs = New List(Of FullName)
            DocSigner.Tabs.DateSignedTabs = New List(Of DateSigned)
            DocSigner.Tabs.RadioGroupTabs = New List(Of RadioGroup)
            DocSigner.Tabs.TitleTabs = New List(Of Title)
            DocSigner.Tabs.DateTabs = New List(Of [Date])
```

Comment: Larry just so you know, I was having a hard time getting the API Logger to work. I got it to Authenticate several times, but would never show the data I needed after request hardly. I only got the true data once out of about 10 times. it would usually show me a lot of other logs besides the request, or nothing at all.Not sure why.

Comment: Hi @Chris Thank you for the report. The logger captures all activity for your account. This can be a problem when what you want is all activity for just your application. I will look into this further as we work to improve the logger.

Comment: Ya I noticed that. It seemed when I signed out online and only ran the API, nothing would show at all for some reason. But after I signed in online all the logs would show, except for what I looking for.